# Semantic Scoring and readability for short sentences

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, language-model

I am working on short sentences for NLP based classification. I wish to make a assessment if a sentence is readable before training the system on it. Now readability scores are not working since readability score indicate how simple a sentence is not how correct a sentence is.

What I am searching for is something that measures(or scores) the readability of a sentence. For example the sentence 'The sun rises in the east' should be given a high score whereas the sentence 'sun the east in rises' should be given a low score.

Is there any python package for this or could someone indicate some direction for it?